# Default picklist value for opportunity

Tags: opportunity, picklist

After winter 19 release, default picklist value is changed from --NONE-- option to next first picklist value.

I would like to reset it to --NONE-- value. can you please let me know that workaround.

PFA screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Have you already reached out to Salesforce support? This does look to be impacted because of the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Default value settings can be managed in many places: Some troubleshooting suggestions:

1. check the Default Value in the field's definition page (in Setup Menu)
2. Open the Object in Setup Menu, go to its Record Types, then change the default picklist value for the field based on the Record Type
3. Look for known issues, the Setup Audit Trail, client-side extensions, and any custom logic that might be causing this.  Test your theories in a new sandbox before testing in production.

Comment: Peter - in this case its the standard field on opportunity and there isn't an option available to set a default value.

Answer (score 0):

We reached out to Salesforce on this, as we too were experiencing the same behavior.

This is now a Known Issue that has been introduced with Winter '19 upgrade and impacts the Lightning Experience only.

Here's the **[issue link](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=opportunity-stage-picklist-is-defaulting-to-the-first-value-in-the-value-set-instead-of-none-when-creating-a-new-record-in-lightning&Id=a1p3A00000031NW)** for further details.